# Como utilizar um script com variaveis? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo criar um JavaScript personalizado:

Ex:

```
var lx = function(addr){window.open(addr, '_self'); }
```

Mas não deu certo.

Utilizei até o visual studio 2012 para editar este script mas o html não reconheceu a função

```
lx('www.google.com');
```

Comment: Você ta executando esses códigos na sequencia e no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Não tem o que dar errado, vide [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWxm6/). Como/onde você está chamando `lx`? O que o seu Chrome Inspector está alegando?

Comment: Por testei aqui no console do Chrome e a unica alteração que fiz pra funcionar foi adicionar http:// no endereço. E funcionou.

Comment: Você tá chamando esse código em que parte do arquivo? Se for em um arquivo HTML tem que ser dentro da tag `script`.

Comment: @user12138, a sua utilização de variáveis está correto. Ou seja, está a passar uma valor corretamente para dentro da função. O que não está claro é o que pretende fazer com o window.open. Pode explicar melhor?

Answer (score 2):

*HTML*

```
<button id="open">Clique aqui</button>
```

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
function open (address) {
    window.open(address, '_blank');
};

var button = document.getElementById('open');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    open('http://google.com');
});
```

E também não esqueça de colocar o `http` no inicio do link, pois poderá ser interpretado como uma pasta.

[DEMO, Obrigado @Guilherme Oderdenge](http://jsfiddle.net/TWxm6/)

Para o seu método funcionar, o código deve ser executado no mesmo arquivo.

*HTML + JAVASCRIPT*

```
<html>
<head>
   /* CSS, SCRIPTS, ETC.... */
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var lx = function(addr){ window.open(addr, '_self'); }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      lx("http://www.google.com");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Outra opção é utilizar o `window.location` caso queira abrir na mesma janela/aba

```
var lx = function(addr){ window.location = addr; }
```

Comment: A sua resposta não faz sentido porque não existe um erro para se basear. O `_self` vai abrir uma janela no mesmo frame em que fora clicado e as chances disso funcionar são maiores que usando o `_blank`. Portanto, negativei. Resposta inválida.

Comment: a função lx(addr) aparece que não existe.

Comment: @user12138 Eu fiz esse [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWxm6/) para você. Dê uma testada – não tem porque dar errado. E Diego, não prestei atenção na sua dica do `http` como sufixo – se possível, edite a sua questão e eu removerei o meu -1.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge código atualizado, falha minha, o problema mesmo é por que estava tentando acessar do JSFiddle o google em iframe, desculpe!

Comment: @DiegoViera Acontece cara! Agora o teu negativo virou um positivaço! +1! :D